# Union with nested list/multiple for loops

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set, union

I have a dictionary like so:

```
myDict = {'items':
            [{'names': [{'longName1', 'shortName1'},
                      {'shortName2', 'longName2'}]},
            {'names': [{'longName3', 'shortName3'},
                      {'shortName4', 'longName4'}]}]}
```

Attempting to get the keys (i.e. shortName) in a set Pythonically. I have the following statement, but it's complaining that `i` isn't defined. What am I doing wrong?

```
shortNames = set().union(*(j.values() for j in i["names"] for i in myDict["items"]))
```

Expected result:

```
set(['shortName1', 'shortName2', 'shortName3', 'shortName4'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to swap the `for` loops:

```
set().union(*[j for i in myDict["items"] for j in i["names"]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing `i["names"]` before `i` is defined by `i in myDict["items"]`.

Comment: Ah...so I need to swap the statements.

Answer (score 0):

See, it is not advisable to chain `list comprehension`s just for the sake of brevity. Since you are asking, one way would be:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> {j for j in (chain.from_iterable(sum([i['names'] for i in myDict['items']],[]))) if j.startswith('short')}

{'shortName1', 'shortName2', 'shortName3', 'shortName4'}
```

Your method could not work:

1. As [dacx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58934314/union-with-nested-list-multiple-for-loops/58934404#58934404) mentioned.
2. `j.values()` would not give you `shortNames` as those are inside `sets` not `dicts`, and `sets` do not have `.values()` method.

---

OR:

```
>>> {j for j in set().union(*(set().union(*i['names']) for i in myDict['items'])) if j.startswith('short')}
{'shortName1', 'shortName2', 'shortName3', 'shortName4'}
```